# Is there a possibility to post message in Discord channel NOT using Bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Typically Discord api proposes to send a message to the channel or DMs via BOT(it shows as Bot in the thread). Is there is also possibility to post it using user account via API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sound like you are trying to [make a self-bot](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-). Let me warn you, that it is against [Discord's ToS](https://discord.com/terms) and you may have your account removed if you get found out.

If you wish to send a message using the API solely without the need of a Bot user, you may find [webhooks](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook) very useful.

Comment: but still there is a possibility to make self bot, right?

Comment: @rebilliony there is. But I wouldn't recommend it personally.

Answer (score 1):

Automating user accounts is not allowed (if I understood your question correctly). Read this for more info: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

Comment: but still there is a possibility to make self bot, right?